# Python read non standard number format

Tags: python, regex, string

What is the fastes way to convert a string to float if it doesn has a standard format?

In my special case I need to read these **strings** and convert them to **float**

```
-7.5-4
7.5-5
```

that correspond to the numbers -7.5E-4 and 7.5E-5

I need the fastest because I'm loading big size files.

Thanks

Comment: What is `-7.5-4`? It it `-7.5 - 4` = `-11.4`? it is not a _non standard format_

Comment: I don't know if it's the fastest way, but wouldn't something like `float(re.sub(r'([0-9.][-+)', r'\1e', mystring))` work?

Comment: I don't know why you got the down votes or the votes to close. It seems like a good question to me. You could use a combination of regex to split the string and string formatting to insert an "E", then convert the string to a float `float('{}E{}'.format(*re.match(r'(-?\d+\.\d+)(-\d*)', test[0]).groups()))`

Comment: thanks guys, at leat you understood the question.  I'll try your options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This lambda works with your test cases (also with a leading '+'):

```
to_num = lambda s: (1,-1)[s[0]=='-']*
                             float(s.lstrip('-+').replace('-','E-').replace('+','E+'))
```

The opening `(1,-1)[s[0]=='-']` takes care of multiplying by -1 if there is a leading '-', then the float conversion strips leading '+' and '-' signs, and replaces embedded '+' and '-' with 'E+' and 'E-', permitting a valid conversion to float.